# CertificateUnknown error when connecting to Heroku Postgres database

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, ssl, heroku, heroku-postgres

So I am in the middle of migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL, and I am building a temporary solution for the migration period to allow my ASP.NET app to connect to my Heroku Postgres database and make use of Entity Framework etc.

So far I have managed to connect to the database from pgAdmin III for windows with no problems, but when connecting from ASP.NET app, I get this error:

> CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
>   . The specified hostname was not present in the certificate.

I am still fairly new to heroku, but it does not make sense why I can connect from pgAdmin with the same settings as my ASP.NET app but it doesn't work in the app itself.

Full stack trace:

> [ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status: A certificate chain processed, but
>   terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust
>   provider. . The specified hostname was not present in the
>   certificate.]
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription
>   description, String message) +44
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf,
>   Int32& pos) +1359
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages() +415
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.GetInitialHandshakeMessages(Boolean
>   allowApplicationData) +336
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.PerformInitialHandshake(String
>   hostName, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates,
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
>   remoteCertificateValidationCallback, Boolean
>   checkCertificateRevocation) +198
>
> [IOException: TlsClientStream.ClientAlertException:
>   CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. Chain status:
>   A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate
>   which is not trusted by the trust provider. . The specified hostname
>   was not present in the certificate.    at
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription
>   description, String message)    at
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf,
>   Int32& pos)    at
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages()    at
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.GetInitialHandshakeMessages(Boolean
>   allowApplicationData)    at
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.PerformInitialHandshake(String
>   hostName, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates,
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
>   remoteCertificateValidationCallback, Boolean
>   checkCertificateRevocation)]
>   TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.PerformInitialHandshake(String
>   hostName, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates,
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
>   remoteCertificateValidationCallback, Boolean
>   checkCertificateRevocation) +289
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout) +1372
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout) +314
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal() +461
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() +4
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.UsingPostgresDBConnection(NpgsqlConnection
>   connection, Action`1 action) +162
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +99
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +87
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +271
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +27
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the
>   database. This usually means that the connection to the database
>   failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the
>   appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find
>   it in the application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +89
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k) +31
>
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +251
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +43
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +627    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +18
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38    System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +83
>
>   Saleboat.Logic.MeetingLogic.CheckMeetingFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
>   filterContext) in C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Saleboat\project-saleboat\Saleboat\Logic\MeetingLogic\CheckMeetingFilter.cs:22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32
>   filterIndex) +176
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32
>   filterIndex) +644
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +197
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +343
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +465
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 10):

With Npgsql 3.1.5 try to use "Trust Server Certificate=true" in connection string.
Example connection string:

```
Server=[servername];Port=[port];User Id=[username];Password=[password];Database=[databasename];sslmode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true
```